# Is it OK to use notification center to reload a UITableView?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uitableview, notifications

I was told not to abuse notification center and because I'm trying to learn proper IOS dev. I found there are several ways of doing things that works but it doesn't mean it's right or most efficient.

Here is an example: I wrote a RSS feed reader app, in a nutshell I use a singleton class to load all data from the web, also download thumbnails then cache each image for my tableview (tableview  cell have post title, thumbnail and date).

Users have the option to refresh data anytime which basically set all my data and thumbnail arrays to nil then refetch new data. (I'm aware all my data disappear so core data would be a better option for this).

So here is the question - I use notification center (default center) from my singleton class to reload and stop the spinner in my tableview controller when the the data is loaded and ready for use. It works like a charm but is this proper IOS programming, in other words is this something I can show to people (job interview etc)? (if not how else would you do this?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with using notification. But personally I think notification is more appropriate for situations that two unrelated objects need to somehow communicate with each other (or related objects, but the relationship is thru multiple nodes, which will lead to cumbersome code to keep references to each other). For your problem, the table view can use RSS singleton directly, e.g.

```
-(void)refreshTapped {

    [[RSSFeed singleton] loadDataWithSuccessBlock:^{
        // Reload the table here
        // Make sure you use dispatch_async to perform GUI work on the main thread
    } failureBlock:^{
        // Handle Error
    }
}
```

where `RSSFeed` is the singleton class that handles loading data. Maybe that's nicer?

Another use of notification is for "global" events, like iOS very often use (e.g. app enter background / foreground) that no one knows exactly whey they happen. An example: if you want to, say, periodically refresh the feeds (without user pressing the button), notification will be a good choice (possibly the only choice).

I have used notification alot in my apps and have never seen a performance problem. The only catch is to add `removeObserver...` when your view is dealloc'ed.

Comment: wow! thank you so much I knew there had to be another way (I haven't yet fully digested objective-c blocks to be able to use in my code). This is much nicer, using notification feels like "cheating" and I rather not use it unless I really have to. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome :) Blocks are extremely helpful (and very neat). Spend some time learning them, and you will never go back to threads. Using success/failure blocks for networking is common pattern in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone need help with this. With the help of Khanh I made some changes in my code this is working for me (although his suggestion is simpler).

```
- (void) refreshTableView
{
    //get data off screen
    //remove all rows and update table
    [self.myArray removeAllObjects];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

    //------------ New Thread ------//
    //do this on a new thread
    //------------------------------//
    //show spinner (this is optional)
    [self.refreshControl beginRefreshing];

    //we could create our own queue or choose to use the global queue.
    //no reason to create a queue just for this task. I use global here

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT,
                                             (unsigned long)NULL), ^(void) {
        // Load Data or reload data here
        [singleton or your load method];

        // Update tableview
        //note this has to be executed on the main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            //Reload data and stop spinner
            [self.tableView reloadData];

            //if you are using an activity view stop animation here
            [self.refreshControl endRefreshing];
        });
    });

}
```